# go to specific cell when a worksheet is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I want to go to specific cell when a worksheet is selected

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Cellselection()
ActiveSheet Goto:="D5"
End Sub
```

That one does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Worksheet_Activate` event of the relevant worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Range("D5").Select

End Sub
```

To use for several worksheets in a Workbook, move the code to `Workbook_SheetActivate` evenrt (inside the `Workbook` level):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Select Case Sh.Name
    Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4" '<-- run it only for sheet's with these names
        Range("D5").Select
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mansour see edited code, put it inside the `ThisWorkbook` module, adjust the `Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4"` to fit the worksheet names you want to include

Comment: Thanks a lot ,sorry I don't know how to thanks  by tags here

Comment: @Mansour you did, when you accept as "ANSWER" :) you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Goto ActiveSheet.Range("D5")
```